# How to serialize a regex to json in python?

Tags: python, regex, json

I'm building an API in `python` which accepts regexes and needs to be able to serialize the compiled regexes back to the original string in a `json` response. I've looked around but haven't found an obvious method of accessing the raw regex from a compiled regex:

```
import re 
regex = re.compile(r".*")
# what now?
```

One approach I came up with was to create a custom `Regex` class that mirrors all functionality but provides access to a `raw` property which I could fallback on when serializing:

```
import re 

class SerializableRegex(object):
    def __init__(self, regex):
        self.raw = regex 
        self.r = re.compile(regex)
        self.r.__init__(self)
```

However this doesn't seem to give me access to the methods of a compiled regex.

The last option, which I may have to go with, is simply mirroring all methods in my custom class:

```
import re 

class SerializableRegex(object):
    def __init__(self, regex):
        self.raw = regex 
        self.r = re.compile(regex)
        self.r.__init__(self)

    def match(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return self.r.match(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

However this seems wholly inelegant. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can access the raw regex string via the `pattern` property:

```
import re
regex_str  = '.*'
regex = re.compile(regex_str)
assert(regex_str == regex.pattern)
```

Comment: So adding `.pattern` to the re.compile(regex_str).pattern your regex will be JSON serializable.

Comment: But this doesn't serialize of flags like `re.IGNORECASE`.